# In SwiftUI, I have two structs that wrap a Shape, one works, one does not, yet I do not see any functional difference in the two

Tags: view, swiftui, shapes

I’ve wrapped two Shape structs.  One works, the other compiles and runs - but always renders a blank area on screen. Yet, I do not see any key difference in the functionality of the two structs ... what’s different about `AnyShape_AlwaysBlank` that keeps it from rendering the shape as a view ?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct AnyShape_Working: Shape {
    
    private let someShapePath: (CGRect) -> Path
    
    // required to conform to Shape 
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        someShapePath(rect)
    }
    
    init<S: Shape>(_ someShape: S) {
        someShapePath = { rect in
            someShape.path(in: rect)
        }
    }
}

struct AnyShape_AlwaysBlank: Shape {
    
    private let someShapePath: Path 
    
    // required to conform to Shape
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        someShapePath
    }
    
    init<S: Shape>(_ someShape: S) {
        let rect = CGRect()
        someShapePath = someShape.path(in: rect)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Circle will appear below")
            AnyShape_Working( Circle() )
            Text("Blank area will appear below")
            AnyShape_AlwaysBlank( Circle() )
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView( ContentView() )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, when `path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path` is called, it actually uses the `rect` that it is passed to create the `Path`.

In the second case, you pre-created the `Path` using a `CGRect()` which is an empty `CGRect`, so the path returned is one the fits into the empty `rect`.  Then when `path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path` is called, you are ignoring the `rect` argument, and just returning the pre-created `Path`.

---

Another way to do it would be to make the struct generic and then store the `Shape`:

```
struct AnyShape<S: Shape>: Shape {
    
    private let someShape: S
    
    // required to conform to Shape
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        someShape.path(in: rect)
    }
    
    init(_ someShape: S) {
        self.someShape = someShape
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you were wanting to use `AnyShape` to unify all `Shape`s into a single type, this *Generic* version won't do that, because it returns a different type for each input shape: `AnyShape<Circle>` for `Circle`, `AnyShape<Rectangle>` for `Rectangle`, etc.  In that case, I'd stick with your `AnyShape` that uses the closure to capture the `Shape` or perhaps make a `func` a `@ViewBuilder` if you were hoping to return multiple `Shape` types from a function.

Comment: I’m kind of seeing what you’re saying ... parts of swift can take a little effort to grasp.  With the init() and the protocol requirement, it’s kind of a brain-teaser as to what rect is the real source.  
Is there a way to give CGRect the proper size in the broken method ... might help me see its problem a little better.   Btw ... thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: In the broken method, change `let rect = CGRect()` to `let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)` and then you'll see the circle.  Of course, this just uses a static rect, and you want to use the one passed in to the `path(in rect)` call.

Comment: Thanks ... I am starting to understand now ... I did exactly what you said (before you typed it, with x: 0, y:0, width: 200, height: 200 ... and saw it push the circle over to the left edge (where the origin was, and in a 200 x 200 bounding box.  So the real source of the passed in rect comes from the required protocol path() function, right ?

Comment: Yes the real rect gets passed in when the Path is requested, and it can be called many times after the shape has been created, so you absolutely have to use the `rect` argument because the `rect` that is passed in could change due to other external factors.

Comment: Are these comments a correct way to understand this? ‘’’’ struct AnyShape_Working: Shape {
    
    // 1. declaring the "protocol-matching" function type
    private let someShapePath: (CGRect) -> Path
    
    // required to conform to Shape
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // 3. calling the function, after it has been defned, with the passed in rect ?
        someShapePath(rect)
    }
    
    init<S: Shape>(_ someShape: S) {
        // 2. defining function
        someShapePath = { rect in
            someShape.path(in: rect)
        }
    }
}’’’’

Comment: Some enlightening things to try: 1) Set a breakpoint in `path(in:)` and examine the `rect`.  Then, change your code to give an explicit frame to the view:  `AnyShape_Working( Circle()).frame(width: 150, height: 150)` and then see what gets pass in as `rect`.

Comment: Sorry ... I guess comments dont observe line breaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221385/discussion-between-richwalt-and-vacawama).